# Sort Knockout Observable Array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sorting, knockout.js

I'm trying to sort a list of physicians on a page by name.  There is a dropdown and the user can select ascending or descending.  Neither one is working.  The UI is not updating at all.

**EDIT:  I've changed the sort code to follow the example on the KO website.
When i step into the code i get an error when I hover over left and it says "'left' is not defined"**

```
function SortDownloadPhysicians(){
    var sortDirection = getSortDirection()
    var sortByParam = getSortByParam()

    if(sortByParam === "name"){
        if(sortDirection === "ascending"){
            self.physicians().sort(function (left, right) { return left.name == right.name ? 0 : (left.name < right.name ? -1 : 1) });
        }else{
            self.physicians().sort(function (left, right) { return left.name == right.name ? 0 : (left.name > right.name ? -1 : 1) });
        }
    }
    else{  //date of birth
        if(sortDirection === "ascending"){
            self.physicians().sort(function (left, right) { return left.dateOfBirth == right.dateOfBirth ? 0 : (left.dateOfBirth < right.dateOfBirth ? -1 : 1) });
        }else{
            self.physicians().sort(function (left, right) { return left.dateOfBirth == right.dateOfBirth ? 0 : (left.dateOfBirth > right.dateOfBirth ? -1 : 1) });
        }
    }
```

Here's my sort function

```
function sortDownloadPage() {

    var sortDirection = getSortDirection();
    var sortBy = getSortBy();


    // sort by name
    if (sortDirection === "ascending") {

        self.physicians().sort(function (a, b) {

             if (a.name().toLowerCase() > b.name().toLowerCase()) {
                return 1;
            }
             if (a.name().toLowerCase() < b.name().toLowerCase()) {
                return -1;
            }
            // a must be equal to b
            return 0;
        });


    } else {

         self.physicians().sort(function (a, b) {

             if (a.name().toLowerCase() < b.name().toLowerCase()) {
                return 1;
            }
             if (a.name().toLowerCase() > b.name().toLowerCase()) {
                return -1;
            }
            // a must be equal to b
            return 0;
        });
    }
};
```

and here's part of the view model

```
 var ViewModels = ViewModels || {};
    (function (ViewModels) {
        var DownloadVM = function (options) {
            options = $.extend({
                physicians: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.physicians || [])
            }, options);


            //********************************************************************************
            // Private properties

            var self = this,
                _physicians = ko.observableArray([]),
                _page = 1,
                _pageSize = 2;


            //********************************************************************************
            // Public properties



            self.physicians = ko.computed(function () {
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(_physicians);
            });
```

UI code

```
<div class="grid-list-group" data-bind="template: { name: 'physicianDownloadTemplate', foreach: physicians }">



    <script type="text/html" id="physicianDownloadTemplate">
        <div class="group-item clearfix" data-bind="fxVisibility: visible">
            <div class="item-col selector">
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked">
            </div>
            <div class="item-col photo hidden-sm hidden-xs" data-bind="click: $root.toggleOpenState">
                <img class="rounded" title="Profile Picture" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/profile-default.png")">
            </div>
            <div class="item-col field name" onclick="$(this).parent().children('.group-item-drawer').slideToggle();">
                <div class="caption">Physician Name</div>
                <div class="value" data-bind="text: name">{NAME}</div>
            </div>
            <div style="float: right;">
                <div class="item-col field date-of-birth">
                    <div class="caption">Date of Birth</div>
                    <div class="value" data-bind="text: dateOfBirth">{DATE OF BIRTH}</div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="group-item-drawer clearfix" style="display: none; clear: both;" data-bind="template: { name: 'downloadItemTemplate', foreach: files }"></div>

        </div>
    </script>
```

Comment: This functionality is built right into Knockout. See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#pop-push-shift-unshift-reverse-sort-splice

Comment: A big problem with the code, as written above is that: `self.physicians().sort()` returns a sorted array; it doesn't modify the original array; so that line is doing nothing.

Comment: Retsam, how do I make it modifiy the original array so that the UI updates?

Answer (score 2):

I typically solve this problem using a computed function. The computed can subscribe to the "sorting" variable, so when it changes, it will recompute based on the new variable. From there, it is simply a matter of returning the appropriate sorting.

```
function vm() {
    var physicians = [
        'smith',
        'grant',
        'foreman'
    ];

    this.sorting = ko.observable();
    this.sortingOptions = ['A-Z', 'Z-A'];
    this.physicians =  ko.computed(function() {
        var sorting = this.sorting(),
            sorted = physicians.slice().sort();
        if (sorting == 'Z-A')
            sorted.reverse();
        return sorted;
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

and in the view

```
<select data-bind="options: sortingOptions, value: sorting"></select>
<select data-bind="options: physicians"></select>
```

Comment: I didn't go into your sorting logic, which is much better than mine, because the question was less about how to sort and more about how to sort using knockout. So don't steal my crappy sorting function, it will ruin your beautiful app.